BERT models are working slow on production
I have trained three BERT models using huggingface transformers. Let's call these models S, T and I models.
The model.py file is as below. init_model() function is for initializing the models. I will be calling that function in main.py
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification

def init_model():
    device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")
    
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("google-bert/bert-base-uncased")
    model_t = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("google-bert/bert-base-uncased", num_labels=2)
    model_s = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("google-bert/bert-base-uncased", num_labels=2)
    model_i = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("google-bert/bert-base-uncased", num_labels=2)

    model_t.load_state_dict(torch.load(r"PATH/TO/MODEL_T"))
    model_s.load_state_dict(torch.load(r"PATH/TO/MODEL_S"))
    model_i.load_state_dict(torch.load(r"PATH/TO/MODEL_I"))

    model_t.to(device)
    model_s.to(device)
    model_i.to(device)
    return model_t,model_s,model_i, device, tokenizer

The predict.py file is as below. predict_fn function takes model, device, tokenizer_fn and text as input and returns the output probability.
import torch
from torch.nn import functional as F

def predict_fn(mdl, device, tokenizer_fn, text):
    encoded_text = tokenizer_fn.encode_plus(
    text,
    add_special_tokens=True,
    return_token_type_ids=True,
    padding=True,
    return_attention_mask=True,
    truncation=True,
    return_tensors='pt',
    )

    with torch.no_grad():
        input_ids = encoded_text['input_ids'].to(device)
        token_type_ids = encoded_text['token_type_ids'].to(device)
        attention_mask = encoded_text['attention_mask'].to(device)
        output = mdl(input_ids,token_type_ids, attention_mask)
    probs = F.softmax(output[0], dim=1)
    return probs[0][1].cpu().detach().numpy()

In the main.py file I am building the API service using Flask as below. Firstly I initialize the models calling the init_model() function. And then I build a get_prediction() function for returning outputs of all three models together for each input text. After that I build the endpoint /predict
from predict import predict_fn
from model import init_model
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
model_t,model_s,model_i, device, tokenizer  = init_model()
def get_prediction(text):
    t_val = predict_fn(model_t, device, tokenizer, text)
    s_val = predict_fn(model_s, device, tokenizer, text)
    i_val = predict_fn(model_i, device, tokenizer, text)
    return t_val, s_val, i_val

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def get_results():    
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    texts = [text for text in data.values()]
    i_vals = np.array([])
    s_vals = np.array([])
    t_vals = np.array([])
    for text in texts:
        t_val, s_val, i_val = get_prediction(text)
        t_vals = np.append(t_vals,t_val)
        s_vals = np.append(s_vals,s_val)
        i_vals = np.append(i_vals,i_val)
        
    return jsonify({
                    "i_scores": i_vals.tolist(),
                    "t_scores": t_vals.tolist(),
                    "s_scores": s_vals.tolist(),
 })

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)

In the current scenario, I send the request to the server as below.
import requests

ip_address = "XXXXXXXXX"
url = f"http://{ip_address}:8000/predict"  
data = {"text1": "TEXT1_COMES_HERE",
      "text2": "TEXT2_COMES_HERE",
      "text3": "TEXT3_COMES_HERE",
         }
    
response = requests.post(url, json=data)
print(response.json())

And I get the response successfully.
The GPU built-on our server is Tesla T4. When I sent request of consisting 1000 texts, I get the respond in 22 seconds which means models can process 44-45 texts per second. And no it is not about slow internet connection or anything. Models are working slow. The models are working on GPU, I checked that. However, I cannot understand where the problem is exactly? How should I optimize the system?
PS. This is my first time deploying a model so in case I am doing something very wrong, don't be harsh please. And also I had to anonymize the code so it might look non-sense at some points, it is mostly because of anonymization. But I am open to any suggestions.

add some timing and logging to make sure that inference is your bottleneck. It could be something else

Do you have multiple workers handling concurrent requests? If you have more than one request trying to run on the GPU concurrently, they will throttle. Your init_model function uses from_pretrained which requires downloading weights for the pretrained model. You can init from a config without doing that. Also make sure your model is actually using the GPU

@Karl yes, it is working on GPU. I do not have multiple workers but even when I sent only one request it is still slow. How should I init from a config?
